# Open-ended concepts in Chinese usually be alluded by listing specific examples. Would native English speakers find it hard to grasp the connotation?

Tags: translation, connotation, hypernyms, linguistics, word-formation

In Chinese and Vietnamese sometimes a word is made up by listing its examples. For example, "table-chair" means furniture, "month-year" means time, "land-water" means country, "spring-summer-fall-winter" means the cycle of time, "birth-old-sickness-death" means the cycle of life. Of course words for "furniture" or "time" exist, but by using "table-chair" or "month-year", the alluded concepts are more flexible, fluid or open-ended.

For example, a chest, although is a piece of furniture, would never be considered as "table-chair" when you consider the word "table-chair" alone. But if you say you've bought "table-chair" for your new home, it is assumed that you've also bought chest, bed, fan, sofa, etc.

Some other best fruits of this:

- **spring-summer-fall-winter**: after spring summer will come, after winter spring will come. Seasons are just an endless circle.
- **birth-old-sickness-death**: even when you're healthy like a newborn, you'll ultimately get sickness, then get older, then die. Life is a sequence of stages.
- **joy-anger-love-hate**: similar to "spring-summer-fall-winter"

I think commas can be used to list them as example and then explain the concepts like I just did above.

## Question 1

Can native speakers feel the open-ended connotation if they read a translation of this kind of word? Can "spring, summer, fall, winter" evokes the feeling of the cycle of time in them, or is it just a list of seasons? I'm afraid that the component words are too specific so the native readers would overlook the implicitly concepts. What would be a good consideration to transfer the open-endedness in English?

## Question 2

I am taking a next step by putting them together:

> **No alter formatting**
>   Birth old sickness death, spring summer fall winter, joy anger love hate, these stages are so vividly clear.
>
> **Use commas**
>   Birth, old, sickness, death; spring, summer, fall, winter; joy, anger, love, hate; these stages are so vividly clear.

Is it too much commas?

<sup>This phenomenon is called *hyponymous juxtaposition* (same type words stick together to create a cover word). The component words are called *hyponyms*, the cover words are called *hypernyms*. See [What is the term for alluding to a more formless concept by listing its specific members?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/29035/19233)</sup>

Comment: _"Can native speakers feel the open-endedness connotation if they read a translation of this kind of word?"_ Depends on the particular words. To me, `birth-old-sickness-death` seems clear enough; `month-year` and `land-water` don't.

Comment: What do you feel about "spring-summer-fall-winter" and "joy-anger-love-hate"?

Comment: Safe for genericized trademarks, English doesn't do this. Obviously any human can understand what "birth-old-sickness-death" must mean, but if you use it in a translation from Chinese, it will sound just like that: a translation from Chinese. It will sound decidedly un-English. It is not something a native English speaker would produce. And yeah, month-year, land-water or table-chair are right out of the window. If you are shopping for furniture, you are shopping for furniture and not just chairs. (Though again, you totally might add a hoover and some sellotape to your cart.)

Comment: To give a better idea of what you mean by this open ended concept, and how an open ended concept of furniture differs from the concept of 'furniture', could you perhaps give is some example sentences?

Comment: @Spagirl a drawer, although is a furniture, would never be considered as "table-chair" when you consider the word "table-chair" alone. But if you say you've bought "table-chair" for your new home, it is assumed that you've also bought drawer, bed, fan, sofa, etc.

Comment: @RegDwigнt that's why I would use commas instead of dashes. In Chinese it simply writes as "birth old sickness death", but I guess in English we can write "birth, old, sickness and death". But in my article, I use "spring summer fall winter, birth old sickness death, joy anger love hate", and I don't know how to translate this properly.

Comment: @Ooker Well 'a drawer' is *part of a piece* of furniture, a 'chest' or 'set' of drawers is a piece of furniture, we wouldn't talk about 'a furniture'. The sets of words wouldn't work in the same way in English. Can you give us examples of how the life and time sets would be used, and edit the examples into the question?

Comment: There might be a good way to do this in English, but I think you're going to need to add some context—What sentences would you use this in?

Comment: @Spagirl thanks, I didn't check the word carefully. I've updated the question, is it better?

Comment: @Laurel please see my update

Comment: Even if this is the case in Chinese, in English it looks like a form of poetic expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current approach to question 2 is:

> Life or death, right or wrong, love or hate, all of them are so vividly clear.